# How to apply style to child component from parent component when we have 2 child component

Tags: css, angular, parent-child

I have a child component that is a spinner, I want to display this in 2 places.
With a different style. I am trying below:

```
my-loading-overlay ::ng-deep .loading:after {
  top: 80px;
}
```

it is working for the first one as expected but **how to changes style for the second child component CSS property top:150px**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Searching for `:nth-of-type(2)` ? [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare those styles globally and not use ::ng-deep since it is deprecated. See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

try something like this:

```
<my-loading-overlay class="first"></my-loading-overlay>
<my-loading-overlay class="second"></my-loading-overlay>



my-loading-overlay {
  display: block;

  &.first {
    .loading:after {
      top: 80px;
    }
  }

  &.second {
    .loading:after {
      top: 20px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but didn't work for me  & showing an error for me

Comment: What is the error? Did you put the scss in the styles.scss ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your parent component:

```
// add first-one and second-one attributes to be able to select with css
<my-loading-overlay first-one></my-loading-overlay>
<my-loading-overlay second-one></my-loading-overlay>
```

```
my-loading-overlay[first-one] ::ng-deep .loading:after {
  top: 80px;
}

my-loading-overlay[second-one] ::ng-deep .loading:after {
  top: 150px;
}
```